# SOAP-ERROR: Parsing WSDL: Couldn't load from 'wsdl' : failed to load external entity "wsdl"

Tags: php, web-services, soap, wsdl

```
$params = array (
     "AccountName" => $_POST['comp-name'],
     "DBA" => $_POST['DBA'],
     "Comment" => $_POST['comments']
 );

$options = array(
        'soap_version'=>SOAP_1_1,
        'trace'=>1,
        'exceptions'=>1
    );
    $context = stream_context_create($options);
try {
$soap = new 
    SoapClient('https://application.cloud.clickandpledge.com/Signup.svc?wsdl', $options);
    $soapParams = array('instruction'=>$params);         
    $response = $soap->AccountSignUp($soapParams);
}
catch(Exception $e) {
    die($e->getMessage());
}

var_dump($response);
```

I amusing above to code snippet to connect with SOAP using my WSDL file, Where i am getting below error in my screen..

**SOAP-ERROR: Parsing WSDL: Couldn't load from 'http://application.cloud.clickandpledge.com/Signup.svc?wsdl=wsdl0' : failed to load external entity "http://application.cloud.clickandpledge.com/Signup.svc?wsdl=wsdl0"**

Answer (score 0):

You don't seem to have the correct WSDL URL.  The one I found is:

https://paas.cloud.clickandpledge.com/PaymentService.svc?wsdl

For your SOAP calls, you would then call the "PaymentService" service.  It doesn't look like clickandpledge.com allows a sign-up via SOAP.  You probably have to do that via their webpage.

HTH,
Jim